# how to access element of an array in angular 5

Tags: typescript

I know this is the most basic question but I can't seem to figure it out.

this is my code

```
getInstabul(): void {
    this.homeService.getWeather()
    .subscribe((weather) => {

      this.instanbulWeathers = weather
      // console.log(this.instanbulWeathers);
    });
```

this is my service

```
getWeather(): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get<any>(this.getWeatherUrl())
    .pipe(
      tap(weather => console.log(weather || 'not working')),
      catchError(this.handleError('getWeather', []))

      // this.getWeatherDetails();
    );
```

it returns

```
[…]
​
0: Object { title: "Istanbul", location_type: "City", woeid: 2344116, … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

when I log it [weather] in the console.

but I dont get any any value when I try to log [weather.title]
I want to be able to get a value which I will pass to another function in then component.

help, I am new to angular

Comment: *when I try to log [weather.title]*: show us **that** code. Tell us where it's located.

Comment: If `weather` is an array, then you should access an array element, *then* try to get data from the array element. This is just JavaScript; it has nothing to do with Angular (or even TypeScript) at this point, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JBNizet, I agree, but for some reason its not working. its funny but I have being on this for hours

Comment: You agree with what? All I said was : show us the code that doesn't work as you expect. You haven't, so we cant explain why it doesn't work. The problem happens, I quote, "when I try to log [weather.title]". And none of the code you posted does that.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weather` is a one-element array, so use `{{ istanbulWeathers[0].title }}` in your template.

Or set `istanbulWeathers` to `weather[0]` and then `{{ istanbulWeathers.title }}` should work in your template.

Comment: I want to get each element say `weather.title` (this is because I want to pass the value to another function in my component/service) in my component or service. my template is fine.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you can use `weather[0].title`, etc. from within your component code, or you could add a `map` call in your service to unwrap the array before returning the result to the component.